# Error:MissingRegistration in GCM with asp.net

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

I have following code which give "Error:MissingRegistration" response from GCM server.

```
public void SendPushNotification()
    {

        string stringregIds = null;
        List<string> regIDs = _db.Directories.Where(i => i.GCM != null && i.GCM != "").Select(i => i.GCM).ToList();
        //Here I add the registrationID that I used in Method #1 to regIDs
        stringregIds = string.Join("\",\"", regIDs);
        //To Join the values (if ever there are more than 1) with quotes and commas for the Json format below

        try
        {
            string GoogleAppID = "AIzaSyA2Wkdnp__rBokCmyloMFfENchJQb59tX8";
            var SENDER_ID = "925760665756";
            var value = "Hello";
            WebRequest tRequest;
            tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            Request.ContentType = "application/json";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

            string postData = "{\"collapse_key\":\"score_update\",\"time_to_live\":108,\"delay_while_idle\":true,\"data\": { \"message\" : " + "\"" + value + "\",\"time\": " + "\"" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\"},\"registration_ids\":[\"" + stringregIds + "\"]}";

            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

            dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            string sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
            TempData["msg1"] = "<script>alert('" + sResponseFromServer + "');</script>";
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)tResponse;
            string statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

            tReader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            tResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

But exact string returned by 'postData' posted by Postman or Fiddler gives positive response and notification arrived at device.

What I'm missing in my code please help me.

The `postData` returns this value which successfully posted by Postman And Fiddler

```
{"collapse_key":"score_update","time_to_live":108,"delay_while_idle":true,"data": { "message" : "Hello","time": "5/13/2016 5:50:59 PM"},"registration_ids":["cXMf6hkYIrw:APA91bGr-8y2Gy-qzNJ3zjrlf8t-4m9uDib9P0j8GW87bH5jq891-x_7P0qqItzlc_HXh11Arg76lCOcjXPrU9LAgtYLwllH2ySxA0ADSfiz3qPolajjvI3d3zE6Rh77dwRqXn3NnbAm"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is in **`ContentType`**

Instead of using this:-

```
Request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

**Use**

```
tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
```

It will work

Comment: one more question what if I've more than 100 devices?

Comment: @صفي just pass all the registration ids in your stringregIds variable it will work

Comment: GCM allow only 1000 devices at a time.

Comment: yeah GCM allow 1000 devices at a time. you can do it by using loops and also check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975904/how-to-send-push-notification-to-more-then-1000-user-through-gcm) it will surely help you

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
private string SendGCMNotification()
    {
        try
        {
            string message = "some test message";
            //string tickerText = "example test GCM";
            string contentTitle = "content title GCM";
            string registration_id = "cXMf6hkYIrw:APA91bGr-8y2Gy-qzNJ3zjrlf8t-4m9uDib9P0j8GW87bH5jq891-x_7P0qqItzlc_HX‌​h11Arg76lCOcjXPrU9LAgtYLwllH2ySxA0ADSfiz3qPolajjvI3d3zE6Rh77dwRqXn3NnbAm";
           string postData =
            "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + registration_id + "\" ], " +
              "\"data\": {\"contentTitle\":\"" + contentTitle + "\", " +
                         "\"message\": \"" + message + "\"}}";

            string GoogleAppID = "AIzaSyA2Wkdnp__rBokCmyloMFfENchJQb59tX8";

            WebRequest wRequest;
            wRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            wRequest.Method = "POST";
            wRequest.ContentType = " application/json;charset=UTF-8";
            wRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            wRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            var stream = wRequest.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Close();

            var wResponse = wRequest.GetResponse();
            stream = wResponse.GetResponseStream();
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var response = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wResponse;
            var status = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

            reader.Close();
            stream.Close();
            wResponse.Close();

            //TODO check status
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return "sent";
    }
```

Comment: can you show me the data in stringregIds variable. i think there is problem in passing registration ids

Comment: it depends on conditions. Currently only one user registered but in future many will be there.

Comment: postData =
              "{ \"collapse_key\":\"score_update\",\"time_to_live\":108,\"delay_while_idle\":true,\"registration_ids\": [ \"cXMf6hkYIrw:APA91bGr-8y2Gy-qzNJ3zjrlf8t-4m9uDib9P0j8GW87bH5jq891-x_7P0qqItzlc_HXh11Arg76lCOcjXPrU9LAgtYLwllH2ySxA0ADSfiz3qPolajjvI3d3zE6Rh77dwRqXn3NnbAm\" ], " +
                "\"data\": {\"time\": " + "\"" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\", " +
                           "\"message\": \"" + value + "\"}}";

Comment: pass your registration id directly instead of passing through variable and check is it working properly or not??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111911/discussion-between-r-c-and-).